# Show parent category title just once in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop, categories

I got a while loop that is looping through a custom post type called "dealers".

Every dealer has a parent category and some of them got child categories.

I want to show the name of a parent category just once inside the loop but it doesn't work.

I got this code so far but now it shows "Nederland" 3 times because there are 3 dealers with the parent category "Nederland".

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;

$titel_categorie = false;

if($cat_name == "Nederland" && !$titel_categorie)
{
    echo "Nederland";
    $titel_categorie = true;
}
?>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <span class="dealer-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('plaats'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('telefoonnummer'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('website'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('e-mailadres'); ?></span>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I used this method once before and it did work but now it doesnt.

Does anyone have another suggestion?

**EDIT**

Thanks everybody for the answers, some of them worked a bit but not solving the complete issue where I'm in now.

I managed to partly get it to work placing it outside the while loop but I also got subcategories.

```
<?php 
$titel_categorie_nederland = false;
$titel_categorie_belgie = false;
$titel_categorie_italie = false;
$titel_categorie_polen = false;
$titel_categorie_noord_brabant = false;
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;


if($cat_name == "Nederland" && !$titel_categorie_nederland)
{
?>
<div class="col-lg-12"><h3>Nederland</h3></div>
<?php
    $titel_categorie_nederland = true;
}

if($cat_name == "Polen" && !$titel_categorie_polen)
{
?>
<div class="col-lg-12"><h3>Polen</h3></div>
<?php
    $titel_categorie_polen = true;
}

if($cat_name == "Belgie" && !$titel_categorie_belgie)
{
?>
<div class="col-lg-12"><h3>Belgie</h3></div>
<?php
    $titel_categorie_belgie = true;
}
if($cat_name == "Italie" && !$titel_categorie_italie)
{
?>
<div class="col-lg-12"><h3>Italie</h3></div>
<?php
    $titel_categorie_italie = true;
}
?>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <span class="dealer-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('plaats'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('telefoonnummer'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('website'); ?></span>
    <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('e-mailadres'); ?></span>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is working but not a clean way of coding and looking at the future not smart to do it this way when a new country is added.

I got a custom post type dealer, main category are countries and subcatory are provinces. Is there a way to show it like this with a cleaner code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTsNF.jpg

Comment: I think it's because of `while(..` part of code.

Comment: maybe in other posts' terms you have `land_titel == "Nederland"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did this before inside a while loop, no problems there... but for some reason it aint working now

Comment: so maybe data are different now

Comment: Ok, I tried something else, the extra foreach loop was not nesesary. I now only use the while loop but still no luck. See edited answer.

Comment: Could you please show data of 'posts' ? I guess you have 3 posts which each of them has a dealer with 'cat_name = "Nederland"'

Comment: the data of 'posts' is very long, but as you guessed, I got three posts with cat_name = "Nederland" but I only want to show it once

Comment: So simply put `$titel_categorie = false;` before `while`

Answer (score 1):

Using [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) will stop your loop from running

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $land_titel = $term->name;

    if($land_titel == "Nederland" && !$land_titel_nederland) {
        echo "Nederland";
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to break your loop within another loop (e.g. your while loop), you can use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $land_titel = $term->name;

    if($land_titel == "Nederland" && !$land_titel_nederland) {
        echo "Nederland";
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that allready, still got three results instead of just one

Comment: maybe try var_dump($post) and var_dump($term) in your foreach so you can see what data you're working with and what's causing it to return into the statement? Just so you can know how to rearrange your loops.

Comment: I changed my code, not using a foreach loop anymore. When I use break, the whole loop stops... not just the if

Comment: @user2812779 updated my answer for you, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php

$post_type = 'dealers';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( array( 
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'parent'   => 0
    ) );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :

        echo "<h1>".$term->name."</h1>";

        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=-1" );

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <span class="dealer-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
          <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('plaats'); ?></span>
          <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('telefoonnummer'); ?></span>
          <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('website'); ?></span>
          <span class="dealer-plaats"><?php the_field('e-mailadres'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif;

    endforeach;

endforeach;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set outside the loop (while)

```
$titel_categorie = false;
```